# STOMP Protocol - Connect frame are login / passcode mandatory?

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp

I have been using the STOMP protocol in various guises. I have experienced this phenomenon in the PHP, Python and Objective-C libraries for STOMP. The STOMP specification on [the STOMP website](http://stomp.codehaus.org/) is not specific on this point.

Basically, the CONNECT function in all three libraries (although the Python one has now fixed this, it was acknowledged as a bug. The function still sends a login and passcode parameter, even if none are specified. As so..

```
CONNECT
login:
passcode:
```

The specification is unclear, and I am wondering if anyone has any better idea about this. I am aware some people involved with STOMP and ActiveMQ browse these forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveMQ does not require these headers to be sent. Take a look at this telnet session for example

```
$ telnet localhost 61613
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
CONNECT

^@
CONNECTED
session:ID:nc-example.com-51165-1234432649359-2:0
```

It connects successfully to the broker without any headers.

Cheers

Comment: Agreed.  My read of the spec is that the login/passcode headers are optional.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the [STOMP 1.1 specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#CONNECT_or_STOMP_Frame) clarified this ambiguity stating:

> STOMP 1.1 clients MAY set the following headers:
>
> - login : The user id used to authenticate against a secured STOMP server.
> - passcode : The password used to authenticate against a secured STOMP server.